# How to change materials in .mtl file using Aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm using aframe to load an .obj and .mtl, everything seems fine. However, i'm not able to change the materials of child nodes. Has anyone overcome this before ?

This is what I have done so far

```
 < a - entity id = "model" position = "0 0 0" 

< a - entity obj - model = "obj: #tree-obj; mtl: #tree-mtl" position = "-.35 
0 .55" rotation = "0 -20 0" scale = "1. 1. 1." > < /a-entity>

< /a-entity>
```

Java script code to traverse the children

```
var tex = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "tex.jpg" );
    var cover = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            name:"set2",
            map:tex,
            specular: 0x0f8191,
            emissive: null,
            emissiveIntensity : null,

   } )



  var el = this.el;


         el.object3D.traverse(function( child ) { if (child.material.name == "set2")  {

                                                            child.material = cover;

                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                        child.material.needsUpdate=true;
                            }    
    });
```

Kindly let me know where i'm missing out.

Comment: Have you waited for the model to load?

Comment: @ngokevin off course, i can see the model, however unable to change the .mtl according my will

Comment: I mean wait for the model to load before you run the code.

Comment: @ngokevin, yes i'm performing this after obj mtl load

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where is the JS being called, how you're waiting for the MTL to load. Thanks!